# safe to assume microsoft core fonts would be installed on client linux?

Tags: website-design, fonts

How safe is it as a web designer to assume that `msttcorefonts` would have beeb installed on a client machine viewing my website? If not what sans serif fonts should I use then? (for body)

Answer (score 4):

> Safe to assume Microsoft core fonts
>   would be installed on client Linux?

No, Microsoft's core fonts are typically not included with Gnome or KDE installations.

You can use `font-family:sans-serif` to specify the *default* sans-serif font on any client machine (i.e. `font-family:Arial,sans-serif`)

Answer (score 2):

Consider font embedding:
http://jumpingfishes.com/font/

If you don't like that option, I agree with danlefree's suggestion of using `font-family: sans-serif;` to get the default sans-serif font.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, I just use similar fonts (in shape, etc) that are told to be common in most distributions, and of course, they come in font-family tag after Arial or verdana or whichever I want windows users to see , so linux users will see the alternative ones instead.

For a clue, I (I use mostly san serif fonts, similar to arial, verdana, etc) tend to set these : Nimbus Sans L, FreeSans, Bitstream Vera Sans, Liberation Sans, Dejavu.

Anyway, I set always first those fitting better my design, as many linux do have those as well (often Arial, verdana, etc)

You have [here](http://www.codestyle.org/css/font-family/sampler-UnixResults.shtml) a relation of most common fonts in linuxes, udpated last february.

Last note: You might be interested in having an vmware virtual machine in Windows for trial and error in using these alternative fonts. I do this quite often myself. (we at Bitnami have VMWare virtual machines with [Drupal](http://bitnami.org/stack/drupal) or other CMSs already all set and configured)